# How do I exclude a class from CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, frontend, styling

I have the code:

```
.et_pb_text_inner a {
color: #fff;
}
```

If I want to exclude make sure this excludes ".et_pb_image_wrap", how would I do that?

Comment: you mean what by *to exclude*. By default a CSS declaration like this exclude everything else but `.et_pb_text_inner a` (links inside .et_pb_text_inner)

Answer (score 1):

So you're only wanting to apply the style if it also doesn't have that class?

```
.et_pb_text_inner:not(.et_pb_image_wrap) a {
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: am pretty sure this won't work, not sure if a wordpress plugin will put a class for image and one for text to the same element .. so better wait for the HTML sctructure and more details

Answer (score 0):

If .et_pb_text_inner a is affecting .et_pb_image_wrap then this is probably a matter of inheritance. A detailed writeup on inheritence in CSS may be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance).

My guess would be to set

```
.et_pb_image_wrap{
  color:revert;

}
```

Or

```
.et_pb_image_wrap{
  color:initial;

}
```